# lvalue doesn't designate an object after evaluation?

Tags: c, c99, language-lawyer

C99 [Section `6.3.2.1/1`] says

> An lvalue is an expression with an object type or an incomplete type other than void;
>   **if an lvalue does not designate an object when it is evaluated, the behavior is undeﬁned.**

What does the part in **bold** mean? Can someone please explain it with an example?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Null pointers, pointers to deallocated objects and pointers to objects with automatic storage duration whose lifetime has already ended come to mind. Dereferencing these results in invalid lvalues; the undefined behaviour you will encounter most often are segfaults if you're lucky, and arbitrary heap or stack corruption if not.

Comment: The C Standard waives jurisdiction over the effects of attempting to evaluate any pointer expression which doesn't yield a null pointer, a pointer to an object, or a pointer just past an object.  From its standpoint, there's no such thing as a pointer to an object whose lifetime has ended, since it defines no circumstances where evaluation of a pointer expression could yield such a pointer.

Answer (score 6):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int* ptr;

void f(void) {
    int n = 1;
    ptr = &n;
}

int main(void) {
    f();
    // UB: *ptr is an lvalue that is not an object:
    printf("%d\n", *ptr);
    return 0;
}
```